What's the [definition] tag for?
Currently the tag definition has 35 questions. No tag wiki excerpt is available. The dictionary definition of "definition" (how meta...) is:

a statement of the exact meaning of a word, especially in a dictionary.

6 of these questions are also tagged cc-cedict (and incidentally all were asked by @Becky). In this case, it's clear enough that [definition] is related to a CC-CEDICT entry.
Among the remaining 29 questions not tagged [cc-cedict], it appears what most of them are asking is the meaning of some term. In those cases, the tag [definition] seems kinda overlapping with [meaning] / [meaning-in-context], or [difference], or possibly [translation].
Since there are 6 questions tagged only with definition, we can maybe examine those first:

Why/how does 说 mean update in 下次再说?. I would tag this [meaning-in-context]

What is the difference between 國語 and 普通話?. I would tag this [difference]. Possibly [taiwan], possibly [usage].

Is there a word for 1/3?. Possibly [word], surely not [definition].

How is “戚” Being Used as a Standalone Verb to Mean “Feel”? [closed] (rightfully closed)

What is this character used for: 夰 [characters] seems appropriate, and exhaustive.

What does 旧币 refer to exactly?. [definition] is actually appropriate.



It seems there are a few instances where the tag is actually useful and/or helps disambiguate the scope of the question. So synonyms and burnination might be unwarranted. Instead some careful retagging could be beneficial.
What do you think?

EDIT:
I proposed a tag synonym from [definition] to [meaning], please feel free to vote on that

I just noticed there is also a [dictionary] tag (70 Qs).  Hmm...

I think you're quite right:

definition a statement of the exact meaning of a word, especially in a dictionary.

That's a fairly strong argument for adding the synonym definition -> meaning.  Done and merged too.  (30 July 2020)
It seems like we should also merge I've now merged cc-cedict into meaning.  As I think cc-cedict is broader (encompassing website questions), I don't think I'll create a synonym.

definition  I went through them all, retagged a few, and I'd feel comfortable for all the definition tags to be changed to meaning.  (Although many should be retagged further.)

What is an accurate translation of 自立自强?
Is 金口难开 an idiom, and if so what would be a suitable CC-CEDICT definition?
What's the difference between 老公 (lǎo gōng) and 丈夫 (zhàng fu)?
What is the significance of 女娲补天 beyond its literal meaning "Nüwa mends the sky"?
What's a suitable CC-EDICT definition for 各司其职?
Are "gratitude" and "appreciation" suitable CC-CEDICT definitions for 感激之心?
Is this an example of chaining adjectives?  I think definition here not the best; it seems it relates to the definition of "chaining adjectives".  But it is about the meaning of the given sentence.
Does the chengyu 话不投机 (huà bù tóu jī) mean "uncongenial speech"?
Does 飛機 mean "airplane" or "aircraft"?
Difference between 图画 and 绘画
List of fixed character descriptions (eg. 白勺的)  Perhaps definition is not appropriate here---it's not about definitions.
Why does 牛车水 mean Chinatown?
Why/how does 说 mean update in 下次再说?
What's the difference between 战略 and 策略？
What is the difference between 國語 and 普通話?
What does 尿尿 mean?
Interesting "bullet points"  I just retagged it.  (It could use a better title, but I can't think of one immediately.)
What is this character and what does it mean? (Characters identified: 仁爱)  I just retagged it.
What's the difference between 差異 and 差別?
Is there a word for 1/3?  I just retagged it.
What is the connotation for gay蜜 and 闺蜜?
How is "戚" Being Used as a Standalone Verb to Mean "Feel"?
Is 了 a pictogram (象形字)?
What is this character used for: 夰
What is the difference between 喝 and 饮?
"我被他当做(了)自己的儿子。" 干爹 gāndiē or 教父 jiàofù?
Translation of "繟"
Difference between 两 and 二?
What does 旧币 refer to exactly? Perhaps meaning-in-context or nuance
What does "强横" mean when it is used to describe an inanimate things?
The meaning of "宝藏"?
What is the meaning of 么?
Clarifying usage and definition of 怀疑
What is a "亲传弟子" and how would you say it in English?

cc-cedict

What is an accurate translation of 自立自强?
Is 金口难开 an idiom, and if so what would be a suitable CC-CEDICT definition?
What is the significance of 女娲补天 beyond its literal meaning "Nüwa mends the sky"?
What's a suitable CC-EDICT definition for 各司其职?
Are "gratitude" and "appreciation" suitable CC-CEDICT definitions for 感激之心?
Does the chengyu 话不投机 (huà bù tóu jī) mean "uncongenial speech"?
中东 - "Middle East" or "Eastern China"?

Indeed meaning in all of these works fine.

PS. if you're interested, I clicked "view source" on the definition and cc-cedict pages and copy/pasted the result into temp.html, then I used the following command to generate the lists:
grep "<h3><a href=\"/questions/" temp.html | cut -d"/" -f3 | awk '{print "- https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/" $1}'


proposed a tag synonym [definition] -> [meaning]
